# How could we find the cost resulted from using kubernetes pods in azure in particular subscription?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, cloud, devops

I am deploying my application inside kubernetes pods. I need to find only the portion of the cost that is resulted from running pods in my monthly billing cycle. I am wondering, if there is any script or KQL for this task.

Comment: Have you looked at the Consumption API?

Comment: this doesnt make any sense, really. why? how do you factor in all the variables that exist in the process (how often releases are made, how much traffic each pod generates, how often backups are made, storage costs, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You need to tag the resources in azure that are tied to workloads running in kubernetes. Using the tags you should be able to identify the associated cost for billing cycle